# Fork retry error when using awk -v within shell script

Tags: bash, awk, sh

When I run my script....

```
#!/bin/sh

input1=$1
input2=$2

awk -v FILEIN=$(echo $input1) '

NR==FNR { 
        a[$1]=$2; 
        next
        } {
        if ($19 < $20) 
                print $0, substr(a[FILEIN],$19,$5) ;
        else print $0, substr(a[FILEIN],$20,$5)}' $input2 $input1
```

by running

```
sh script.sh 030-031 lookup.txt
```

SOMETIMES I get an error: "script.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable"

If I avoid passing a shell variable and explicitly state FILEIN (which is impractical)...

```
#!/bin/sh

input1=$1
input2=$2

awk '

NR==FNR { 
        a[$1]=$2; 
        next
        } {
        if ($19 < $20) 
                print $0, substr(a["030-031"],$19,$5) ;
        else print $0, substr(a["030-031"],$20,$5)}' $input2 $input1
```

..the script works. I can't get around this by using ARGV[1] in place of explicitly stating the variable, I think because awk won't expand $input1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes for the awk script instead of single quotes?  You'd need to escape all the `$` and `"`, but you'd then be able to use `$input` directly.

Comment: @Trenin I would say that is not a good way do to it.  Use single quote and declare variable with `-v` or after the code.

Comment: @Trenin. Thank your for your solution. I hadn't thought of that and it works. However, I agree with @Jotne that it's not ideal though and passing a variable once with `-v` WOULD be better (particularly as the path of `$input1` is not always constant). @Jotne, can you expand on how I might avoid the error message by declaring the variable "after the code" as you say.

Comment: What's wrong with `awk -v FILEIN="$1" ...`? Although unexpected, it seems the command substitution is bumping you up against a limit on the number of processes your shell can have at once.

Comment: @chepner I think you might be right - although I can't confirm because currently everything is working. OUt of interest - why would your method `awk -v FILEIN="$1" ...` use fewer processes?

Comment: That's good circumstantial evidence, since failure depends on the machine load :)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with awk. It's your SHELL that's reporting an error:

```
script.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

It could be that your shell doesn't support `$(..)` for command execution, or that using unquoted variables in your `echo` arguments are causing problems, or that your `echo` is broken or something else.

What it is NOT, though, is anything to do with awk or `-v` other than the fact you're populating an awk variable using a shell command that your shell doesn't like.

Try either of these:

```
awk -v FILEIN=$(echo "$input1") '...'
awk -v FILEIN=`echo "$input1"` '...'
awk -v FILEIN="$input1" '...'
```

to see which works. Best I can tell that last one should be all you need.

Oh, and NEVER use double quotes to delimit an awk script as someone else suggested. That just leads to all sorts of quoting and escaping problems and potential for nightmarish failures and/or error messages given some values of shell variables.

Finally - always quote your shell variables unless you have a very specific result you're trying to achieve by leaving them unquoted and fully understand all of the caveats and implications for word splitting, globbing, etc. of doing so.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try this. However, as I mentioned before the problem is sporadic and currently i'm not getting any error. I think @chepner may be correct - I may be reaching a limit on the number of file descriptors or processes. As soon as I get confirmation that one of these solutions works i'll post.